# Having a problem simplifying if statement

Tags: python

Using Python.
I want to create a very simple system that tells python that ammo consumption will be true if full capacity get decreased by 1, and when ammo consumption be true later I would make python know that an ammo got consumed. The problem with my code is that the ammo consumption keeps being True.

Here is the code if you did not understand:

```
# fc means full capacity, and that number will tell the player for an example how much arrows they have
fc1 = 10
fc2 = 20
fc3 = 30
fc4 = 40
fc5 = 50
fc6 = 60
fc7 = 70
# If Wanted to use capacities in a list
full_capacity = [fc1, fc2, fc3, fc4, fc5, fc6, fc7]
# It is false because it did not get consumed yet
ammo_consumption = None
# it means that if r_approval is True then in the defined later reload system it can get reloaded if the player
# of course press a specific button
r_approval = False
# just to clean an error
o_o_o_o_o_o_o_o_o = r_approval
# checking
print(fc1, ammo_consumption)
# here I tell python how it works
if fc1 > 9:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
if fc2 > 19:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
if fc3 > 29:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
if fc4 > 39:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
if fc5 > 49:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
if fc6 > 59:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
if fc7 > 69:
    ammo_consumption = True
    r_approval = True
shot1 = fc1 - 1
print(shot1, ammo_consumption)
shot2 = fc2 - 1
print(shot2, ammo_consumption)
shot3 = fc3 - 1
print(shot3, ammo_consumption)
shot4 = fc4 - 1
print(shot4, ammo_consumption)
shot5 = fc5 - 1
print(shot5, ammo_consumption)
shot6 = fc6 - 1
print(shot6, ammo_consumption)
shot7 = fc7 - 1
print(shot7, ammo_consumption)
# but here ammo_consumption is still true
print(ammo_consumption)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with “if fc1 - 1:”? This will always evaluate to True unless fc1 = 1

Comment: you can use this community https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for reviewing your code.

Comment: For the first one I was just checking if it works when I do fc1 - 1, but I forgot to change it sorry.

Comment: You say "but here ammo_consumption is still true" - but how were you expecting it to be otherwise?  Once you set `ammo_consumption` to `True`, there is no code (at least within the fragment you posted) to set it to any other value.

Comment: I expected it to be True when it knows that the player used a function that decreases the fc1 by 1 in each shot like the shot1 example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace a lot of your code by changing it to a loop. Try this

Instead of defining 7 variables to store values 10 thru 70 and then store it into a list, you can use a single line to create that. See the definition of full_capacity.

Also, instead of checking for each condition, you can just iterate thru the list to check for the value.

And finally, you can assign shot as a list based on values in full_capacity.

Like the rest of the folks that provided you feedback, I am still not sure what you are trying to do. All if conditions will be true because you are not changing the values.

```
full_capacity = [i for i in range(10,80,10)]

for i in range (7):
    if full_capacity[i] > (i*10 + 9):
        ammo_consumption = r_approval = True

shot = [(i - 1) for i in full_capacity]
print(shot)
```

Also, if you can define the actual problem statement, we may be able to help you. Let us know what you are trying to do with your code. There may be an easier way to solve for it.

Comment: If you mean an error that pops up like a TypeError or else then no but I thought when I do an if condition a thing will not be True anyways. + about changing a value can you give me simple example of changing a value

Comment: I will pick just one variable and walk you thru the code. You set fc1 = 10.
then you check  if fc1 > 9. It will always be true. You never changed the value of fc1. hat results in ammo_consumption and r_approval = True. Then you are setting shot1 variable to fc -1 which equates to 9.

At each step, you are just setting values and printing. There is no code that alters the values of fc1 thru fc7. So your entire code will result in True and assignments.

What are you trying to achieve with this code? Provide some more context and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not being repeated. However, if you were expecting ammo_consumption to be false after the lines:

```
# shot{i} = fc{i} - 1
```

This does not happen because:

1 -  Python code is read sequentially, and variables are not updated post-assignment.

2 - You are not changing the value of any of the variables fc1, ..., fc7.

Comment: but didn't  I change the value in shot1?

Comment: @Help_ME_AM_NOOB No, all you did was *assign* the variable shot1 to the value fc1 - 1.

Comment: Hm then how can I do it right? like should I do a function about it? or there is something else